# React this.state updates only visible after some time and not immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to understand something about reacts state. I looked in the docs but didn't find anything that could help me get my head around this. Suppose I have a component similar to:

```
class Login extends React.Component {

  state = {
    emailError: null,
    passwordError: null,
    email: "",
    password: ""
  };

 validateEmail = () => {
    const { email } = this.state;
    console.log({email});
    this.setState({ emailError: email.length === 0 ? 'Email is required' : '' });
    setTimeout(() => {

    }, 100);
  }

  handleChange = (field, value) => {
    const validationMethod = `validate${capitalize(field)}`;
    this[validationMethod]();
    this.setState({
      [field]: value
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.loginUser}>
        <TextInput
        placeholder="E-mail"
        errorMessage={emailError}
        fixed={Boolean(this.state.email.length)}
        onChange={(ev) => this.handleChange("email", ev.target.value)}/>
        // some other components.
        <ContextButton label="Login" isActive={this.shouldSubmitBeActive()} classNames={['continue']} onMouseEnter={ this.triggerValidation }/>
      </form>

    );

  }
```

The problem is that when the form is first empty, and you type something in, `console.log({email})` shows:

`Object {email: ""}`

When I type another character in the field, the console.log would show the first character but not the second. So if the input is 'ab' it would show:

`Object {email: "a"}`

However, if I put the code inside a setTimeout:

```
  validateEmail = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const { email } = this.state;
        console.log({email});
        this.setState({ emailError: email.length === 0 ? 'Email is required' : '' });
    }, 50);
  }
```

The console.log shows what I expect.

What concept am I missing here ? What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks =)

Comment: `setState` is not synchronous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

> [`setState()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)
>   does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state
>   transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can
>   potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState
>   and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Also from the docs:

> The second parameter is an optional callback function that will be
>   executed once `setState` is completed and the component is re-rendered.
>   Generally we recommend using `componentDidUpdate()` for such logic
>   instead.

So if just want to log state changes, you can pass a callback to `setState()` that will be executed *after* state is mutated:

```
this.setState({ 
  emailError: email.length === 0 ? 'Email is required' : '' 
}, () => console.log(this.state.emailError));
```

Comment: It just feels weird to put that setTimeout in there.

Comment: I'm logging for testing purposes, but the state would get passed down to child component. But the callback in the setState is the thing to do. Thanks !

Comment: @AndresZapata It *is* weird to put that `setTimeout` in there; normally you wouldn't need to do anything like that essentially ever. It's also a little suspect, because state updates may also be batched--you're always at the mercy of React internals and you can't really guarantee anything.

Comment: @Dave Newton Yes. I had read about the setTimeout callback but completely forgot about it. This is my second React project so hadn't faced this problem yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the order of operations is incorrect in your code. Your console.log happens before you `setState`. Referencing Hunter McMillen's answer, however, fixing the order will not likely fix the problem.

There are various solutions for problems like this. The simplest one for you would be simply passing the value as a parameter to the `validateEmail` function. For organizing more complex projects, a flux-like framework such as Redux may be useful.

Comment: I am using redux but for more general state objects, not form validation. Using setState with a callback does the trick.

Comment: Depending on your project, timeouts like these might cause trouble. If your component is destroyed before the timeout, then `setState` will be called on a non-existing object, which, if I remember correctly, results in an error.